# Upload App on App store by different account.?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have uploaded the iOS app by one apple account (currently, app is not approved). Now I want to upload this app by other apple account. And I will delete the app by first account. After that can I upload this app by other account. 
Please suggest can I upload this app by other account without changing the name of app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need the same account to upload your app to appstore as it would use same distribution certificate, Provisioning profile and Bundle identifier.

Otherwise you may go for App Transfer.

Refer :- 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html